# javascript - how to make quick load website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a shop website , I have a problem with seo and loading time ,when I check my website with gtmetrix , it shows me this result :

total page size : 5.5mb
load time 6.5 s

I check some shops and I get this results for example

total page size : 350kb
load time 1.5 s

but it has lots of images and content either /.

I think they load the content via javascript after the page has loaded

How can I do so ? How can I make it load fast and then get the images and contents ?

thanks

Comment: How would downloading files through JavaScript make smaller files?

Comment: You can try Lazy loading for images and other stuff

Answer (score 0):

1. Use minifier to minify your js and css code.
2. Serve your static assets from cdn
3. use Lazy Loading for Images

Answer (score 0):

Is your website a single page application? If yes then loading in the content via a separate AJAX call would be possible allowing your users to view the basic webpage first and then the content and images later.

Otherwise there are a number of ways you could optimise:

1) Concatenate and minify all your JS and CSS to reduce file size and number of files downloaded.
2) Allow caching. You will have to set this up from your webserver.
3) You could optimise your images by removing unnecessary meta info if any.

GTMetrix's report should list down the ways your website specifically could be optimised. Take some time to go through that report.